# Proving convergence in distribution identitity

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $\{Y_n\}$ converges in probability to $0$. How would I show that $\{X_n + Y_n\}$ converges in distribution to $X$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem

Comment: How would I use Slutsky's theorem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this: you have to demonstrate that for every continuous function with compact support $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ you have $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n+Y_n)]\to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

Now, $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n+Y_n)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)]+\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]$ and since $X_n\to X$ in distribution, it is enough to show that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)]\to 0$.
For this, take $\delta >0$. Then you have
$$
  \begin{multline*}
    \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)|]
    =\\=
    \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)|I_{\{|Y_n|>\delta\}}]
    +
    \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)|I_{\{|Y_n|\leq \delta\}}]
  \end{multline*}
$$

But
$$
  \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)|I_{\{|Y_n|>\delta\}}]
  <
  2M \mathbb{P}[|Y_n|>\delta]\to 0,
$$
since $Y_n\to 0$ in probability ($M=\sup|f|$).
And
$$
  \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n+Y_n)-f(X_n)|I_{\{|Y_n|\leq \delta\}}]
  <
  \epsilon
$$
for every $\epsilon >0$ if $\delta$ is small enough, since $f$ is absolutely continuous.